# java PDFBOX rotate rect

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to rotate a rectangle with the Apache PDFBOX Library but I've googled it and nothing shows up. Here's some of the code:

```
PDPage page = document.getPage(i-1);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,page, true, false, false);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
contentStream.addRect(dto.getLeft(), dto.getTop() - factY, dto.getWidth(), dto.getHeight());
contentStream.fill();
contentStream.close();
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? What are the actual rectangle values? Does it work if the 5th PDPageContentStream constructor parameter is true? Do you save the result? If possible, share the PDF.

Comment: Version 2.0.20
The rectangle values i get this from a custom visor in vue.js. The rectangle is print well but the rotation not.

Comment: What rotation? I see no rotation in the code. Your code draws a filled black rectangle.

Comment: Yes, I ask for the exact code to be able to paint the boxes with rotation, for example if it comes to me from the frontend the rotation of the box at 105º so that the rotated box is painted with those degrees

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer for PDFBox 2.0.* which draws a box rotated around its bottom left origin:

```
// draw a filled box with rect x=200, y=500, w=200, h=100
contents.saveGraphicsState();
contents.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(105), 200, 500));
contents.addRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
contents.fill();
contents.restoreGraphicsState();
```

Now change `Math.toRadians(105)` to the desired angle and you have your rotated rectangle.

You seem to be using an older version of PDFBox. I strongly recommend to use 2.0.* instead.